# Second Part of nested loop confusion?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i'm sorry for asking on here but I've watched countless videos and read a bunch but i still cannot wrap my head around nested for loops. I understand that while the outer loop runs once, the inner loop will run x amount of times. I've heard the analogy of a clock, somewhat.

This for example:

```
var arr = [
  [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
];
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

I understand the first loop will iterate through like so [1,2], [2,4], [5,6];
as 0,1,2.

however what happens with the inner for loop? will it iterate through 1,2 3,4 5,6? Or will it just go over 1, 2, 5? If someone could please help me get over this brain blockage i would reallllly appreciate it!

Comment: _"will it iterate through 1,2 3,4 5,6?"_ Yes

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: add a brakepoint and debug. you can see what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct with the first loop. Since arr.length is 3 it will iterate like 0,1,2.

The inner loop will iterate through your inner arrays depending on their lenghts `arr[i].length`.

So in your case 0,1 for every inner array, cause `arr[i].length` is 2 for every of your inner arrays.

This is an example of a slightly modified array:

```
var arr = [
  [1,2], [3,4,7], [5,6]
];
```

Now `arr.length` still is 3, so the outer loop interates: 0,1,2

But the inner loop iterates:

- 0,1 for i = 0
- 0,1,2 for i = 1
- 0,1 for i = 2

Because `arr[0].length` and `arr[2].length` are 2, while `arr[1].length` is 3

Answer (score 1):

> will it iterate through 1,2 3,4 5,6?

Yes, exactly, because we start with the `[1, 2]` array and loop through its contents, so we output 1 and then 2, then we move on to the `[3, 4]` array and loop through its contents, outputting 3 and then 4, and finally the `[5, 6]` array, outputting 5 and 6.

The best way to verify and understand these things is to step through them with a debugger. There's a fully-featured debugger built into every modern desktop browser; built into any decent JavaScript IDE; and for environments like NodeJS if you don't have an IDE that handles it for you, you can use things like `node-inspector`.

Answer (score 1):

its pretty simple.
See you have one outer loop

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

As arr have 3 elements `i` will iterate as 0, 1, 2.

Now for each 0,1,2 , you have an inner loop

```
for (var j=0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
```

So say when `i = 0`, j will iterate from `0 to arr[0].length` i.e. `0 to 2`
when i = 1, j will iterate from 0 to arr[1].length, and so on.

Now what happens inside the inner loop:
There is a console log for arr[i][j]. So

```
i = 0, j = 0, arr[0][0] = 1
       j = 1, arr[0][1] = 2
i = 1, j = 0, arr[1][0] = 3
       j = 1, arr[1][1] = 4, and so on...
```

So when you check the console, you get 1,2,3,4, so on...

You might also Run the following code:

```js
var arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6]
];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop result in console will be like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```